# SQL Server ip/port mapping to 3rd party app

Tags: sql-server

Not sure if this is possible, I have a SQL Server 2012 database that I need to transmit data to a third-party app on a specific IP/port. Is this possible. If so, how do you 'map' to an specific ip/port? Trying to avoid writing middleware. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create the endpoint, e.g., `CREATE ENDPOINT MyEndpoint STATE = STARTED AS TCP (LISTENER_PORT = 50001, LISTENER_IP = ALL) FOR TSQL();`. If you want to use a specific address, the address must be in parentheses, e.g., LISTENER_IP = (10.0.0.201). Note that By default, access to the default TCP/IP endpoint is revoked for public role when a new TCP/IP endpoint is created
2. Modify access on the new endpoint using GRANT / DENY CONNECT
3. Add the port specified in the LISTENER_PORT as a new TCP/IP port in the SQL Server Configuration Manager (i.e., WinKey + R / MMC / menu File / Add/Remove Snap-in / SQL Server Configuration Manager / Add / O.K. / SQL Server Configuration Manager)
4. Restart the SQL Server

Depending on the scenario you want to do with user endpoints, sometimes it can be very tricky to make the SQL Server do what intuitively should work without problems. Therefore, it’s useful to test the user endpoints. Check the error log what IPs and ports the SQL Server is listening on. Also try to connect to the SQL Server and verify that your connection is using the desired endpoint. E.g. :

```
SELECT * FROM sys.endpoints WHERE endpoint_id = (
SELECT endpoint_id FROM sys.dm_exec_connections WHERE session_id = @@SPID;
);
EXEC sys.sp_readerrorlog 0, 1, 'listening'; -- Returns only 'listening' rows
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. This is the kind of information I am looking for. I was considering using CLR as I am not familiar with ENDPOINT, but ENDPOINT has the potential to be a better solution.